# Convert View to PDF (more one page)

Tags: java, android, pdf, bitmap, pdf-generation

I have a dialog containing text and images from user input, and I want to convert it to pdf (A4 size page).
When I convert the window to bitmap and then to PDF, The bitmap is not complete because the page size is not enough ..

How I can create a new page if the first page is not enough and prints the remaining bitmap on it?

```
private Element generatePdfFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(view);
        document = new PdfDocument();


        PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595,842,1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page myPage = document.startPage(myPageInfo);
        
        Canvas canvas = myPage.getCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);
        document.finishPage(myPage);

        createFile();

        return null;
    }





private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {

        Bitmap ImgBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ImgBitmap);



        Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null){
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        view.draw(canvas);

        return ImgBitmap;


    }
```

How I can create a new page if the first page is not enough and prints the remaining bitmap on it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

1. Scale the bitmap down to fit on a page by working out from your bitmap/view width/height scale factor needed to fit 594 x 841 pixels and the `myPage.setScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);`
2. Or better don't try and use a bitmap as it is very difficult to split in a nice way on to multiple pages of a PDF. And the size/layout of a view used to display on screen won't work for a large, low resolution A4 Page.

So draw a view specifically created for the PDF directly to the PDF page (this produces a better PDF with selectable text and smaller in size).

If you pre-measure the view items you can work out how many fit on a page.

And Example of how to pre-measure and draw directly to multiple pages in a nice way is at https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf (This gets it's views from a recyclerview but the concept is the same of drawing multiple views to a PDF).